# I simply want to upload a new build to an existing version. Keep getting ERROR ITMS-90062

Tags: build, version

I am trying to understand why I keep getting this error.

ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [0.0.2] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [3.11]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"

Although we are building our app using Ionic / Cordova, the actual app is built using Xcode.

In Xcode 11.5, it is clearly marked as:
 - Version: 3.11 
 - Build: 0.0.1

and when I go to AppStore Connect -> Activity, the current version that is marked as "Ready for Sale" is:
 - Version 3.11 
 - Build 0.0.1

[image]

To me, it should be a simple process.  It I have a small fix, I want this to be **Version 3.11, Build 0.0.2**

'Version' is for major fixes/new features, and 'Build' is for minor fixes (typos, color changes, other aesthetics).

Yes, when I try to upload Version 3.11, Build 0.0.2 to the Appstore Connect, I get the ERROR ITMS-90062.

[image]

Any advice? I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Derek

Comment: Can someone help please.  I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!  The lightbulb went off :)

Each approved app must have a new, increasing Version Number.
We can upload multiple builds to App Store Connect (and TestFlight), each with an increasing Build Number, for any Version Number.  Only when testing is complete, then we submit one of those Builds for approval..and hence a new version bump.